# How to grab class from mutations.target?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers, mutation

I am using this snippet of code below to log mutations.target.

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
    //console.log(mutations, observer);
    // ...
    
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.target);
    }); 
});

// define what element should be observed by the observer
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
  //...
});
```

**The specific element below (Example):**

```
VM2246:9 <div id=​"1873868e7868ba9363aa46100a9cf976" class=​"tw-border-radius-medium tw-font-size-6 tw-inline-block tw-inline-tooltip tw-pd-05 tw-semibold" style=​"max-width:​ 300px;​">​380 cae-bucks​</div>​
```

So how do I grab the class name from mutations.target? Unfortunately the documentation is really bad.

Comment: Which documentation were you reading? If the target is an element, it'll have the standard `.className` property.

Comment: Just the documentation on MutationObservers from mdn + the other 10 sites that regurgitate each other. 


Both lines DON'T work.
`console.log((mutations.target).className);` and `console.log(mutations.target.classList);`

What am I missing?

Comment: `console.log(mutations.target.className);` doesn't work either. :(

Comment: It's `mutation.target`, not `mutations.target`.

Comment: Yeah I am a tard. Thanks.

Comment: If you put this in a post I'll "Accept the Answer" if you care enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
mutations[0].target.classList // this returns an array of all classes
mutations[0].target.className // this returns a string containing all the classes separated with an space
```

Comment: `VM2610:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`

In both instances (Well different wording, but you know what I mean). 


`console.log((mutations.target).className);` doesn't work either

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer